# How to scroll the page to make a field completely visible

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a client database with a form where the client's treatments are listed below the main data in a continuous form. For each treatment there are fields for treatment dates, medications etc and a 4-line note field with a scroller. This works very well.

The problem is when the current note field is partly hidden at the bottom of the page. Say only two lines are visible. As the user enters more data, the text will be hidden beyond the bottom of the page and he has to use the vertical scroller for the main form.

Is it possible to somehow automatically scroll the page as more text is entered, or alternatively reposition the page when the note field gets focus to make sure it is completely visible?

*Please note that the field in question is part of continuos form as this probably affects the solution.*

Comment: research floating shapes in excel

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit on that? I have googled and read about floating shapes but so far I haven't been able to see how it is related to my question.

Answer (score 0):

What you are wanting is for your form to behave similar to the way that forms behave on web pages, with boxes that can expand when needed. This isn't possible in MS Access.

You mentioned "reposition the page when the note field gets focus". It's unclear what you mean as the term "page" really only applies to reports in MS Access. I'm assuming you probably mean "form" and you are hoping to somehow reposition the form when the note field gets access. Without seeing the design of your form, I cannot see how this could possibly resolve this problem. Also, my own experience is that trying to manipulate the exact position of a record in a continuous form in Access is not feasible. I won't say that it can't be done but I somewhat doubt that you'll get something like this to work reliably.

I suggest you instead build in the ability to open the Notes field in a larger popup (maybe modal) form. This will allow you to give the user a lot more space to view and edit notes. To avoid write conflict errors you will either need to save the record before opening the Notes popup or else you will need to make the Notes popup window an unbound form that uses some global or public variables to pass data back and forth between your original form and the popup form. If you go with the latter option, just pass the notes to the Notes popup when you open the form, using the opening arguments. And then pass the data back to the original form by using a form level public property or variable, or else by using a global variable. If you open the Notes Popup form using the acDialog argument you will be able to check the value of your public/global variable in the next line of code since execution of the code goes into "hold" when using acDialog.